# Textfield not accept arabic languages

Tags: objective-c

When I type arabic languages on textfield it doesn't allow anything in textField. how to make Arabic language on textField.

---

I changed simulator language as arabic but not accepted in texField. One of the textfield accepts but another textfield letters not showing in arabic language. If any settings in textfield to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

use the localization search it google and understand and apply in your project in localization...
another technic is simulator in keyboard change language ....